# Почему команда pip3 list из активного виртуального окружения выводит список глобальных зависимостей (пакетов) вместо зависимостей окружения?

Tags: python, ubuntu, zsh

В общем вопрос в следующем. Пытаюсь разобраться с утилитой **pyenv**. Создал для теста каталог с именем **“test”**, а уже в нем три других каталога в именами **“foo”, “bar”** и **“baz”**. Для каждого вложенного каталога создал свое собственное виртуальное окружение по шаблону:

```
pyenv virtualenv <intepreter version> <nameOfVirtualEnv>
```

Затем для каждого каталога установил свое локальное окружение с помощью шаблона вида:

```
pyenv local <nameOfVirtualEnv>
```

Затем решил проверить список всех установленных пакетов для каждого виртуального окружения по отдельности с помощью команды

```
pip3 list
```

и тут, вместо ожидаемого пустого списка мне вывалился список **всех** **глобально** установленных пакетов/зависимостей(!)
Далее я выполнил в терминале для каждого из четырех каталогов команду:

```
which python
```

на что получил вывод:
 ***/usr/bin/python***
т.е. для родительского каталога **“test”** (что вполне ожидаемо, т.к. для него я **НЕ** устанавливал локального окружения) и вложенных трех каталогов (а вот тут уже неожиданно).
Люди, подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может крыться причина такого поведения ?
Где и что мне поправить (какие файлы), чтобы при вызове из текущего виртуального окружения команды

```
pip3 list
```

, в терминал отображались только те зависимости, которые установлены для активного виртуального окружения ?
Иными словами, как мне добиться поведения, когда при вызове команды

```
which python
```

из каталога foo выводилось что-то вроде
 ***/home/neon/.pyenv/versions/fooVenv-3.7.4/bin/python***
, а не
 ***/usr/bin/python***

(Рисунок№1 - Скрин терминала)

[image: Скрин терминала]

Как вы можете убедиться, во всех четырех случаях команда `which python`выводит один и тот же путь к системному интерпретатору Python, что для каталогов "foo", "bar" и "baz" не есть адекватным поведением.

Для них, эти пути должны быть, что-то вроде:

- */ home / neon / .pyenv / versions / fooVenv-3.6.5 / bin / python*
- */ home / neon / .pyenv / versions / barVenv-3.7.4 / bin / python*
- */ home / neon / .pyenv / versions / bazVenv-3.9dev / bin / python*

соответственно, что собственно и обеспечивает изоляцию окружений друг от друга.

(Рисунок№2 - Результат команды `pip3 list` из каталога **"test"**)

[image: Скрин терминала]

(Рисунок№3 - Результат команды `pip3 list` из каталога **"foo"** с активированным виртуальным окружением **"fooVenv-3.7.4"**)

[image: Скрин терминала]

Как видно из рисунков 2 и 3, команда `pip3 list` выводит идентичный результат.

Интуитивно понимаю, что надо пошаманить где-то с путями в файлах настроек терминала типа **.zshrc, .zshenv** и им подобными, но в силу небольшого опыта использования Linux не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: Окружение нужно активировать: source 
/home/neon/.pyenv/versions/barVenv-3.7.4/bin/activate